# How can I define an interface in an exported Typescript class?

Tags: typescript

This code to use jQuery Data Tables in Typescript works fine:

```
interface JQuery 
{
    dataTable: any;
}

class Grid extends Widget
{
    public data: any;

    public someMethod()
    {
        //apply datatables to the grid element
        $('#someId').dataTable(this.data);
    }
}
```

But now I need to `export` the grid class for use in another module. When I try this, however, I get this error:

```
Error   146 Property 'dataTable' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
```

How can I preserve my interface for jQuery to be able to use the `datatable` method, but be able to export the class?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare interface in external module, it becomes a new interface that is not merged with internal interface. So you should just move interface declaration to separate `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Is the module automatically external once I export a class? This interface is *outside* of the class that's exported.

Comment: If file defines external module, interface from this file become invisible from outside. So it is a new one and not merged. It is like you declare `JQuery2` interface.